# PHPMailer erro ao conectar

Tags: php, phpmailer

Eu estou tentando enviar um email de meu **Localhost**, porém não consigo.

Meu code:

```
<?php
require_once('config/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
//
//$email = $_POST["email"];
//
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//
$mail->IsSMTP(true); 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = 'mygmail@gmail.com'; 
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';
//
$mail->From = "mygmail";
$mail->FromName = "hello";
//
$mail->AddAddress($email, 'assunto');
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject  = "hello!"; 
$mail->Body = "oi teste";
$enviado = $mail->Send();
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
if ($enviado) {
  $error = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
}
else {
  echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
  $error = "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Erro:

```
The following From address failed: myemailhere@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected
```

Eu já liberei a conta para dispositivos no google, ja tentei mudar ssl pra tls também. O email e senha também estão corretos.

Comment: Aparentemente está tudo certinho, verifica só o host se esta correto. verifica se o e-mail do destinatário esta correto mesmo, muda para outro, faça diversificações do código.

Comment: Tentei :( Mudei o email que envia, o email que recebe, a porta do smpt, o programa que uso localhost, mensagem, script também :( até a senha do email já mudei. Sabe alguma alternativa?

Comment: Tentei outras versões do phpmailer também.

Comment: A porta smtp do Gmail é `465`